# Select items in array based on a property value

Tags: json, select, jq

As a developper, when I use the following JQ command:

> .first_level."second_level"[] |= select(.fruit == "pear")

And I apply it to this JSON:

```
{
  "first_level": {
    "second_level": [
      {
        "fruit": "apple"
      },
      {
        "fruit": "pear"
      },
      {
        "fruit": "banana"
      },
      {
        "fruit": "donuts"
      }
    ]
  }

}
```

Then I would like to have this output (only keep the items that have the property `fruit` equal to `pear`):

```
{
  "first_level": {
    "second_level": [
      {
        "fruit": "pear"
      }
    ]
  }

}
```

But the current value that is returned is (can also be seen in JQ Play [here](https://jqplay.org/s/78zotLbF0y)):

```
{
  "first_level": {
    "second_level": [
      {
        "fruit": "pear"
      },
      {
        "fruit": "donuts"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

--> It keeps the value with `donuts` and what I don't understand is that from the JQ documentation, the `|=` should assign the value of the selection but when running:

> .first_level."second_level"[] | select(.fruit == "pear")

I've the following result:

```
{
  "fruit": "pear"
}
```

--> It seems to select succesfully but the affectation doesn't behave as I expect (it adds the `donuts`).

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: .first_level."second_level"[] | select(.fruit == "pear")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your sample input what that program does is basically this:

```
.first_level.second_level |= (
    delpaths([[0]]) # apple != pear
  | delpaths([[1]]) # banana != pear
  | delpaths([[2]]) # null != pear
  | delpaths([[3]]) # null != pear
)
```

See how the underlying builtin for `|=` is implemented [here](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/ccc79e592cfe1172db5f2def5a24c2f7cfd418bf/src/builtin.jq#L14); when the righthand side of `|=` applied to a path's value, if the result is `empty`, that path is deleted by means of `delpaths`. So the problem is clear, when `.[0]` (apple) is deleted, `.[1]` (pear) becomes `.[0]`; but `_modify` doesn't take that change into account as it takes the list of paths to be modified once at the beginning and doesn't update again, and continues with `.[1]` (banana).

You can use this instead:

```
del(.first_level.second_level[] | select(.fruit != "pear"))
```

Or if you insist on a solution involving `|=`:

```
.first_level.second_level |= map(select(.fruit == "pear"))
```

Comment: Thank! I now understand why this code doesn't behave like I would expect. Thanks so much for the clarification and for the sample you've provided! :)